# Unity 3D Several objects not showing on the screen everytime the level is loaded

Tags: user-interface, object, unity-game-engine, appearance

I have a simple 2D game and I have a strange problem whenever a level is loaded several of the objects that include platforms and enemies won't display on screen and neither do the 2D background but all the objects are there, I can see it in the hierarchy and they are functioning as they should like killing the player and such. They just don't show up on the screen. I was finally able to show them while pausing the player during gameplay and set the z position of the camera to -11 and above but every time the level reloads like after the death of player, the same problem happens.

I even tested it on the mobile device but the same problem occurs furthermore I can't even interact with any of the UI buttons on the level, even though I check that all the code for them is appropriate.

Please help.

EDIT:

[image]

Okay after reading, your replies, I thought may be this will help. O always get these errors every time I load up this project in unity but they disappear once the game is running.

As you can see the platforms and enemies does appear on the camera frustum but when I start the game they disappear.

Comment: You've provided us with some description of the problem, but haven't given us anything concrete to work with. Can you provide us screenshots? Maybe of the camera attributes, and of the attributes of one of these disappearing objects? Are there any scripts that dictate positioning of these platforms and enemies in a level? Please edit your question to include any additional information you feel is relevant, since at present it's tough for anyone to give a concrete answer to this question.

Comment: Added the screenshot and more description to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally found the problem. After lot of head scratching and testing I found that the objects that weren't appearing on screen has their z-position set to -10 which is the same of that of camera's z-position.

The problem was I was using this code to set the position of objects in the Awake method:

transform.position = camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(x, y, 0));

What's actually happening is all the x, y, and z co-ordinates were setting related to the camera's position. So setting the z-position to 10 fixed it for me.

Thanks everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because near clipping of your cam is to high; Set it to 0.1 and try it again.

Comment: Wouldn't that affect all objects, not just some?

Comment: No, it only effects the objects within that range, if some objects have different z values, they might be shown. He also says that when he moves the cam -1 on the z axis (default is -10) the objects are shown, which also indicates this problem.

Comment: Okay, I tried lowering down the near clipping to 0.1 but that didn't solve the problem. Another strange thing is I have some test setup level which I used to unit test stuff and it has the same prefabs and same camera settings with near clipping set to 0.3 but it works.

Comment: Okay, I googled it a bit and it seems that you found a Unity bug. Try to delete the cam and add a new one.

Comment: Well, the next thing that you could try is to make a new project and recreate your test scene. If that still doesn't solve it, you could try an older Unity version. And if that still doesn't solve the problem, then I don't know anything else you can do than reporting an error...